# Decoded value of base64 string when re-encoded(to base64) gives different output

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, base64, decode, utf-16

I'm really confused about something here. When I decode the following base64 string

```
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
```

The output is:

`FZ!?A,�U"WwwwwwwwwXHTransactional: Aaaaaaaa Gggggg
?XU恍Rexample01@gmail.com    QD駴tps://www.abcdefgh.com/endpoint--name?id=62FYPW&valu=2ffg92080f22c50c6grsd349frtyuio9&utm_campaign=Transactional%3A%20Password%20Reset&utm_source=SparkPost&utm_medium=email&utm_term=Transactional%3A%20Pppp%20Mainn&referer=62FYPWGQ{"email_user":"14785243699632.288207406700815289974144","binding":"notifications"}`

But when I try to encode the same output value back to base64 it gives me:

```
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
```

What's happening here?

If `decode(base64_A)` is giving me `x`, and `encode(x)` gives me `base64_B`, how can I generate `base64_A` from `x` or `base64_B`?

Comment: The = is padding. e.g., the original string hasn't been passed to meet the spec. Maybe a crlf at the end? What do you get when you decode your encoded decided string?

Comment: When I decode the encoded decided string I get Reset&utm_source=SparkPost&utm_medium=email&utm_term=Transactional%3A%20Password%20Reset&ref    which is same as what I got when I decoded the first base64 string.

Comment: I can confirm that there is no CRLF at the end :)

Comment: Base64 is supposed to be an even multiple of 4 encoded characters, where `=` is generally used to pad the output if it is short (some base64-based algorithms use other padding characters). Your first base64 string is not padded, but your second base64 string is.  Padding is ignored during decoding, which is why the two encoded strings decode to the same text as expected. Wherever your first string is coming from, the author decided to truncate off the padding.  You can do the same in your second string, if needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is not a padding related issue. I've edited the example strings in the question to make more sense. Please have a look.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you, that answered the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decoded text you have shown contains non-ASCII characters in it. Base64 encodes binary data only, so you have to take character encodings into account when encoding/decoding text.

When encoding base64, a character string has to be charset-encoded to bytes first, such as with UTF-8, and then those bytes can be encoded with base64.

When decoding base64, the result is bytes, which can then be charset-decoded to a character string.

If you use the wrong charset, you will get incorrect results.